# Training a neural network

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to train a neural network to play a game with a snake chasing a target. It's my first attempt to train a neural network. I am using Encog framework in Java with back propagation. To create the training set I record the movements the user make while playing the game.

The neural network consists of 102 input neurons, 200 hidden neurons and 4 output neurons. The first 2 inputs are the x,y coordinates of the target, the 3rd and 4th input are the x,y coordinates of the snakes head, the 5th,6th inputs are the x,y coordinates of the body of the snake after it's head, etc. The first output takes the number 1 if the snake turns left, or zero if it doesn't. The second output is for right, 3rd for up and 4rth for down. The inputs are normalised between 0 and 1.

I have tried to train the network with 30.000 training sets, but when I test it the snake can't find the target. It just make random moves.

How many training sets are enough so the network can be trained properly?
The training set will have some wrong data, for example when I play the game I sometime miss the target and try to reach it again through other route.

What minimum error do I have to use when I am training the network? 
Now I use 0.02. The problem is that, when I train the network, it goes from 0.75 error to 0.05 error in just 35 iterations, but it needs over 1000 iterations to go from 0.05 to 0.02.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad. You will have to experiment with the neural network, obtain empirical results, and decide what to do based on them. There is no universal or general answer to what you are asking about.

Comment: Practically impossible to answer. How much "error" is enough? Maybe 35 iterations are good enough? I have been doing NN back went we came out of the AI winter in the 90s, so take this with a grain of salt, but this encoding should probably be normalized to "head always at (0,0), pointing to (1,0)" or something

Answer (score 1):

> The first output takes the number 1 if the snake turns left, or zero if it doesn't. The second output is for right, 3rd for up and 4rth for down

If I assume turn left-right-up-down is the navigation-like from the snake-view. I think the problem is because your training data sets have an input the position of the snake, but not the direction.

example:

- if you only have one size head at (0,0) and the direction is go up (y positive), and the target is at (3,3), your machine may tell it to turn right. Move the snake to (0,1).
- and then after your position at (0,1), then your training set will tell it to turn right again (because the position of the snake is one the left side of target), but actually it will move the snake to (-1,1)

Comment: I didn't understand it 100%. What you mean from the snake view? I give the value [1,0,0,0] if the user press left, [0,1,0,0] if the user press right, etc. It's not relative to the snake's view, it's absolute.

Comment: hm...what happen if user press right twice? is the snake turn right and then stay in that direction or it turn 180 degree?

Comment: it stays in the same direction

Comment: oh sorry,.. so I have a different assumption, may be you could add that explanation on your question

Comment: np, thanks for the answer